# unexpectedly found nil unwrapping an optional - why do I get that fatal error?

Tags: swift, error-handling, fatal-error

```
for object in users {

                if let user = object as? PFUser {

                    if user.objectId! != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                        self.usernames.append(user.username!)
                        self.userids.append(user.objectId!)

                        var query = PFQuery(className: "followers")

                        query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
                        query.whereKey("following", equalTo: user.objectId!)
```

Why do I get the fatal error on the line which says:

> query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
>                               query.whereKey("following", equalTo: user.objectId!)

I do not understand. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

In your if condition you use `PFUser.currentUser()?`. If this expression is `nil` presumably the condition will be true.

Then, when you force unwrap `PFUser.currentUser()!` you logically get a crash.

The same applies to `user.objectId!`.

Comment: So what should I do specifically? Not unwrap it?

Comment: Can you @Mundi tell me what to do specifically?

Comment: Depending on what you intend your app to do, you could skip the conditional if `PFUser.currentUser()` is `nil`. I am just explaining the principle behind your error - you have to figure out the logic of your app by yourself of course.